# moqui deploy in a non-ROOT folder in tomcat

Tags: moqui

I'm trying to deploy moqui 1.6.3 and runtime in apache-tomcat-8.0.12 in a non-ROOT folder.

I have done below modification in build.gradle:

> *task deployTomcatRuntime << {
>       delete file(tomcatHome + '/runtime'); delete file(tomcatHome + '/webapps/**myweb**'); delete file(tomcatHome + '/webapps/**myweb.war**')
>       copy { from file(plusRuntimeName); into file(tomcatHome + '/webapps'); rename(plusRuntimeName, '**myweb.war**') } }*

After commands: gradle cleanAll, gradle buid, gradle addRuntimeTomcat, myweb.war is deployed in tomcat webapp folder successfully.

After that, I use "http://localhost:8080/myweb" to open the root page, and the login page comes "http://localhost:8080/myweb/Login".

And then I give the username and password and click login, but I'm still in login page without any error.

If I change myweb.war to ROOT.war, it will work fine to log into the system.

I put some debug in framework code, and find that system create a new ExecutionContextImpl when redirect from Login to root page. Below is the place I put the logs:

> *ExecutionContextImpl getEci() {
>         **logger.debug("===========getExecutionContext:"+activeContext.get())**
>           // the ExecutionContextImpl cast here looks funny, but avoids Groovy using a slow castToType call
>           ExecutionContextImpl ec = (ExecutionContextImpl) activeContext.get()
>           if (ec != null) return ec
>           if (logger.traceEnabled) logger.trace("Creating new ExecutionContext in thread
>   [${Thread.currentThread().id}:${Thread.currentThread().name}]")
>           if (!(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() instanceof StupidClassLoader))
>               Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cachedClassLoader)
>           ec = new ExecutionContextImpl(this)
>           this.activeContext.set(ec)
>           return ec
>       }*
>
> impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl [] 
>   ===========getExecutionContext:ExecutionContext in tenant DEFAULT
>   --- 2016-05-02 23:02:51.176 [nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl [] 
>   **===========getExecutionContext:null**
>   --- 2016-05-02 23:02:51.177 [nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG impl.context.ExecutionContextFactoryImpl [] 
>   ===========getExecutionContext:ExecutionContext in tenant DEFAULT

It looks like ThreadLocal has problem in a non-ROOT folder in tomcat, but not sure.
Have anybody deployed moqui in a non-ROOT folder?

Comment: Which version of moqui-framework are you using? A new instance of ExecutionContext is created for every web request (it is a light weight, temporary object) regardless of how the webapp is deployed. There is likely another issue. This is best reported as an issue on github.com/moqui/moqui-framework.

Comment: Thanks your replay. I'm using moqui-framework 1.6.3. I found that ExecutionContext is not the root cause. Because if I deploy in ROOT, I got the same "===========getExecutionContext:null". But it redirect successfully when I deploy in ROOT. I will put this as an issue in github.